# Changing Heading With Buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having trouble with JavaScript. **What I want to happen:** The "Modify HTML content", when clicked, changes the "The Original Content" h1 heading to "The New Content", and when clicked again, the "The New Content" changes to "The Original Content". When the "Delete HTML content" button is clicked, the h1 heading disappears, and when clicked again, the blank changes to "The Original Content." Instead, nothing happens. The h1 heading stays the same. Can someone help?

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Content Change</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="contentchange.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1 id="heading"><b>The Original Content</b></h1>
<br/>
<button type="button" onclick="change()" id="button_one">Modify HTML content</button>
<button type="button" onclick="change_2()" id="button_two">Delete HTML content</button>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
//Code for the Modify HTML content button
function change()
{
var elem = document.getElementById("button_one");

if (h1.value=="The Original Content") 
{h1.value = "The New Content";}
else
{h1.value = "The Original Content";}
}

//Code for the Delete HTML content button
function change_2()
{
var elemtwo = document.getElementById("button_two");

if (h1.value=="The Original Content" || "The New Content")
{h1.value = "";}
else
{h1.value="The Original Content"}
}
```

Comment: Where is variable `h1` defined?

Comment: When `h1` is defined (see Regent above) change the line `if (h1.value=="The Original Content" || "The New Content")` to `if (h1.value=="The Original Content" || h1.value == "The New Content")`

Answer (score 0):

You may need to set the `h1` variable as follows:

```
var h1 = document.getElementById('heading');
```

Then use `innerHTML` instead of `value` to change it.

Also, you'll need to check for the `b` tags, like this:

```
if (h1.innerHTML === "<b>The Original Content</b>" ||
    h1.innerHTML === "<b>The New Content</b>"
   )
```

Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/Ls5osy22/2/

Answer (score 0):

You Need to do one change in HTML i.e replace

```
<h1 id="heading"><b>The Original Content</b></h1>
```

With

```
<h1 ><b id="heading">The Original Content</b></h1>
```

:: Change JavaScript Code ::

```
function change(){
    var elem = document.getElementById("heading");
    if (elem.innerHTML=="The Original Content"){
        elem.innerHTML = "The New Content";
    }
    else{
        elem.innerHTML = "The Original Content";
    }
}

function change_2(){
    var elem = document.getElementById("heading");
    if (elem.innerHTML=="The Original Content" || elem.innerHTML=="The New Content"){
        elem.innerHTML = "";
    }
    else{
        elem.innerHTML="The Original Content"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

... and if you somewhy don't want to use neither `h1.innerHTML === "<b>The Original Content</b>"` nor `<h1 ><b id="heading">The Original Content</b></h1>`, you can use [.textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent).

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Regent3000/o21mwoo5/1/).

```
function change()
{
    var h1 = document.getElementById("heading");
    if (h1.textContent == "The Original Content")
    {
        h1.textContent = "The New Content";
    }
    else
    {
        h1.textContent = "The Original Content";
    }
}

function change_2()
{
    var h1 = document.getElementById("heading");
    if (h1.textContent == "The Original Content" || h1.textContent == "The New Content")
    {
        h1.textContent = "";
    }
    else
    {
        h1.textContent = "The Original Content";
    }
}
```

And just for completeness [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Regent3000/5gdhxdm5/) with how it will be with mentioned in question tags jQuery.